# ICollectionView's CurrentChanged event not working if we create full property

Tags: c#, wpf

when we create auto-property of ICollectionView then CurrentChanged event is working properly after refreshing Employee collection.

```
public ICollectionView EmployeeCollectionView{get; set; }

public EmployeeMasterViewModel(IEmployeeMasterView view, IUnityContainer container)
{
 GetEmployee();
 EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged);
}
```

And when we create full-property then CurrentChanged event is not working.

```
private ICollectionView _employeeCollectionView;
public ICollectionView EmployeeCollectionView
 {
   get { return _employeeCollectionView; }
   set { _employeeCollectionView = value; OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeCollectionView");}
 }


public EmployeeMasterViewModel(IEmployeeMasterView view, IUnityContainer container)
{
   GetEmployee();
  EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged);
}

 void EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    var currentEmployee = EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentItem as EmployeeMaster;
   }
```

please suggest if i missing something.

Comment: Where you are initializing `EmployeeCollectionView`?

Comment: before "EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged);"

Comment: Try by giving default value for '_employeeCollectionView'..

Comment: you should show us your `GetEmployee()` Method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have  you bind EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged event after refreshing employee collection? because if you refreshing employee collection then EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged  connection has been lost.

like-

```
private void Refresh()
 {
   GetEmployee();
   EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentChanged += new EventHandler(EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged);
}
```

Comment: this will leak because you don't unregister the old events which will behave like strong references.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect `EmployeeCollectionView` to change (which seems so, otherwise you would not need an `OnPropertyChanged`, I'd recommend to add the Events in the setter of your property like following:

```
private ICollectionView _employeeCollectionView;

public ICollectionView EmployeeCollectionView
{
  get { return _employeeCollectionView; }
  set
  {
    if (_employeeCollectionView != value)
    {
      if (_employeeCollectionView != null)
      {
        _employeeCollectionView.CollectionChanged -= EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged;
      }
      _employeeCollectionView = value;
      _employeeCollectionView.CollectionChanged += EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged;
      OnPropertyChanged("EmployeeCollectionView");
    }

  }
}


public EmployeeMasterViewModel(IEmployeeMasterView view, IUnityContainer container)
{
  GetEmployee();      
}

private void EmployeeCollectionView_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var currentEmployee = EmployeeCollectionView.CurrentItem as EmployeeMaster;
}
```